# How to get return text from php file with ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making a call with ajax to a php file. All I want to do is get a value back from the php file to test it with javascript. I have tried many many things, but can only get undefined (from the below code).

How can I get "hello" returned from the php file to my javascript?

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "the_file_to_call.php",
   data: {userid: group_id_tb},
   success: function(data) {
        var the_returned_string = jQuery(data).html();
        alert(the_returned_string)
    }
});
```

The PHP file:

```
<?php
echo '<div id="id-query-result>"';
echo "hello";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: The closing quote for the div id is in the wrong place `<div id="id-query-result>"` should be `<div id="id-query-result">`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the code inside PHP like this

```
<?php
$queryResult = '<div id="id-query-result">hello</div>';

echo json_encode(['html' => $queryResult]);
```

Then, change your ajax call

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "the_file_to_call.php",
   data: {userid: group_id_tb},
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
        var the_returned_string = data.html;
        alert(the_returned_string);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @James. I tried putting in your code...the ajax doesn't seem to succeed because it doesn't alert anything. No errors in console either.

Comment: Can you try to use console.log(the_returned_string) to check on the console tab? And check on the Network tab to see the ajax call, does the server return code 200?

Comment: Thanks for your help James, I'll just do that and report back :).

Comment: Yay! I made a error that threw off your original code. Works great now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help :D!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "the_file_to_call.php",
  data: {userid: group_id_tb},
  success: function(data) {
      $('body').append(data);
      var text = $('#id-query-result').text();
      alert(text);
      $('#id-query-result').remove()
  }
});
```

Why not just append the HTML response of your php file then get the text accordingly. You can then remove it after.

Answer (score -1):

There are two changes to be done:

1. Change the `type` to "GET" since you directly call the PHP File.
2. remove the wrapped jQuery method inside the success function and add `.html` as an attribute

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "the_file_to_call.php",
   data: {userid: group_id_tb},
   success: function(data) {
        var the_returned_string = data.html
        alert(the_returned_string)
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmmm thanks for your answer...I just tried your edit but I still get undefined. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your chrome developer console?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your other change to GET instead of POST. I have updated the code to GET but still am getting undefined. There are no errors in the console.

Comment: When I add ```jQuery('#a-test-div-id-in-main-page').html(data);``` I get the whole page output again in the test div I created. Which is confusing because there is nothing like that in my php file output, only the echo.

Comment: The line that you used will get the element that has the ID - `a-test-div-id-in-main-page` in the same page that you call the PHP file and prints out the data. You need to edit the success block of your code like this in order to get data from the other file: ```success: function(data) {
        var the_returned_string = data.html
        alert(the_returned_string)
    }```

Comment: I did try your edit above. It was still coming back undefined weirdly...